# What is the proper way to pronounce אלוה?

Tags: pronunciation

I remember reading something by Rabbi Phil Chernofsky in a recent Torah Tidbits in which he stated it should be pronounced “e-LO-wah”. On Mi Yodeya, I’ve read that that’s a Sephardic pronunciation, and that the Ashkenazic pronunciation is “e-LO-ah”. The name of this site seems to point to the “wah” pronunciation. I can’t find the article in Torah Tidbits.

Comment: Welcome back to Mi Yodeya, Ben!

Comment: To the reopen voters: Do note that there's more to a question than its title. The question that this one was flagged as duplicating asks about all letters which receive a patach and are the final letter of the word.

Comment: @doniel no it only refers to letters that get a furtive patach